# One Step To Backward - Should I Use "To"? Or Avoid it?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

One Step To Backward - Should I Use "To"? Or Avoid it?

One Step To Backward.

One Step Backward.

Comment: I have never heard any native English speaker say "to backward".

Answer (score 2):

*Backward* is an adverb and should not be preceded by *to*. The correct idiom is:

> One step backward

Comment: I think *backward* is an adjective ("*nerdlihc* is code for backward children"), and should not be used here at all. The adverb is *backwards*.

Comment: @Tim: I believe that's only true in the U.K.; in the U.S., they can both be used as adverbs (and many people never use *backwards* at all). [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=went+backward%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cwent+backward%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cwent+backwards%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cwent+backwards%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwent%20backward%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20backward%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20backwards%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20backwards%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Is it safer to write just *One step back*? (As in *One Step Forward, Two Steps Back*)

Comment: The *safest* thing to do is use *backwards* as an adverb, and *backward* as an adjective; I don't think anybody will correct your grammar that way. But you do need to use *backward(s)* sometimes: *walking back* and *walking backwards* are not at all the same thing.

Comment: The OED gives ‘backward’ and ‘backwards as both adjective and adverb.